# Input a number range to mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql

how to input a number range, from 2 text fields, this is my code is seems to be not working, the range function i want it to be inserted to mysql database but this code is just to test if i can get the 2 textfields to connect to the range function. anyone can help me solve this problem?

```
<?php
$from = '.from';
$to = '.to';
$number = range('$from','$to');
print_r ($number); 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>New Waybill</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../img/icon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/forms.css" />
</head>

<body>
<form id="form3" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <p>From:
  <input type="text" name="from" id="form_number" class="from" value="0"/> 
    - To:
    <input type="text" name="to" id="form_number" class="to" value="50" />
  </p>
  <p>Waybill Booklet:
    <select name="waybill_booklet" id="form_list">
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="form_button" value="OK!" />
  </p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you mean to do `$from = $_POST['from'];`?

Comment: Are you expecting that `$from = '.from';` will select the input field with the class `from`? (This is PHP, not JS?!) It is hard to tell what you are trying to do here – but it seems like if you are mixing up concepts and programming languages.

Comment: i am trying to put a range of numbers to the database for example user inputs 1 and 10 then it will insert 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

Comment: tnx for the down vote for my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your php code with this:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $from = $_POST['from'];
    $to = $_POST['to'];
    $number = range($from,$to);
    print_r($number);
}
?>
```

To access a form post in PHP you use the `$_POST` superglobal. More info found here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php.

I've put a check to see if it's empty or not at the start, so when the page first loads it won't attempt to run the PHP code. Presumably you'll then replace the `print_r` with whatever you need to insert the data into your database.

Comment: this is what i wanted, now can you help me sir to insert this into mysql?

Comment: We can help correct problems you're having here, as I've done, but if you want a tutorial on something, you should research that yourself. Then, if you can't figure something out, come back with a specific question. This will get you started: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Comment: thank you, anthonygore. i know how to do it. just this problem with the range thanks for your help.